# Serve pdf file by location in nginx

Tags: pdf, nginx, location

How I can to serve the file:

```
'/webapps/app/static/downloads/privacy_policy.pdf'
```

by address:

```
https://my.site.net/privacy/
```

I try to use location in my nginx, but this not work:

```
location /privacy/ {
   alias /webapps/app/static/downloads/privacy_policy.pdf;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found solution. I move the pdf file in separate directory "privacy". I set the directory as alias and set I set pdf document as an index file:

```
location /privacy/ {
   alias /webapps/app/static/downloads/privacy/;
   index privacy_policy.pdf;
}
```

Comment: Hi, your solution works, but the file is downloaded without name :(

Comment: im getting a 403 forbidden using this solution

Comment: @lopezdp, make sure you have proper file/folder permissions to that location on your server for your nginx process user to read it

Comment: @PonzioPilato If you want to specify the file name, you can use a `Content-Disposition` header (either `attachment` to download the file or `inline` to show its contents in the browser window) as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67628066/7121513).

Answer (score 2):

If you want your URL to remain as /privacy in your browser, you can do something like this:

```
# Handle the case with trailing slash
location /privacy/ {
    return 302 /privacy;
}
# Alias to PDF file and specify content type for browser to display instead of download
location /privacy {
    alias /webapps/app/static/downloads/privacy_policy.pdf;
    default_type application/pdf;
}
```