# Nginx serve a file without the filename in the adress bar

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Is the following behaviour possible only with nginx directives?

I want to visit the page:
https://example.com/xyz
When hitting enter in the adressbar I want an immediate download of the file abc.tst to be presented to the user but the adressbar should not change, it should "stay" on https://example.com/xyz and not go to https://example.com/abc.tst and the name of the downloaded file should not change to xyz.

I have experimented with various rewrite rules, or locations but can't seem to figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) HTTP header to speficy filename different from `xyz`:

```
location = /xyz {
    alias /path/abc.tst;
    add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="abc.tst"';
}
```

You may also need to specify MIME type for this file, use [`default_type`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#default_type) directive, for generic binary data try

```
default_type application/octet-stream;
```

Comment: Thank you, this sounds and looks right an makes sense, but unfortunately it gives me 404, I'll keep trying to correct the mistake which I suspect on my end...

Comment: You need to specify full path to `abc.tst` **including** the filename itself. And I changed `location /xyz` to `location = /xyz`, it is more correct.

Comment: The full (absolute) path did the trick, since I specified a root directory in the server directive I specified a relative path in the alias. Thank you very much, this does exactly what I asked for and helped me a lot.