# How to cofigure nginx to serve a pdf file?

Tags: nginx

I´m trying to serve a pdf file by making a configuration in nginx but I get the following error in the page: 404 Not Found

The configuration is like this:

```
server {

    listen 3002;
    index index.html;
    server_name _;

    location / {

        root /var/www/html/pdf_carpet;
        try_files $uri /index.html = 404;
    }
}
```

pdf_carpet is where the pdf file is.

What could I do or change to be able to serve a pdf file in nginx?

P.S. It works with html files.

Comment: You want to serve a single file? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67628066/7121513) answer. Change the location to `location = / { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried doing that but didn´t work :( Still show error. I put it like this:                                                   
server {
        listen 3002;
        index index.html;
        server_name _;

  location = /pdf_carpet {
       alias /var/www/html/pdf_carpet/file.pdf;
       add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="file.pdf"';
       try_files $uri /index.html = 404;
  }
}

Comment: Do you see a `try_files` directive in the answer I'm referring to? Remove it. And how are you trying to access the file? With the config you show in your last comment (without the `try_files` directive) your PDF file should be accessible with the `http://<your_domain_or_IP>:3002/pdf_carpet` URL.

Comment: And since you are serving a PDF file, add the `default_type application/pdf;` directive to that location.

Comment: Now works but it downloads the file. I want to display the file in the page, not to download it. How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the full location block that should show the PDF file in the browser window under the `http://<your_domain_or_IP>:3002/pdf_carpet` URL:

```
location = /pdf_carpet {
    alias /var/www/html/pdf_carpet/file.pdf;
    default_type application/pdf;
    add_header Content-Disposition 'inline';
}
```

**Update**

If an URI for accessing the PDF file ends with the slash (or it is a root URI as a special case), the above config would not work since an index file name will be appended to such an URI by the nginx (making `location = /path/ { ... }` not match the `$uri` internal nginx variable). For such a case another technique can be used:

```
location = / {
    root /var/www/html/pdf_carpet;
    rewrite ^ /file.pdf break;
    add_header Content-Disposition 'inline';
}
```

Comment: Now works fine. Thank you :) One last question, is there a way I shouldn´t need to put the direction for the carpet? For example, to put just the following as the URL:  http://<your_domain_or_IP>:3002

Comment: Sure, using `location = / { ... }` instead of `location = /pdf_carpet { ... }` as I suggested in the very first comment.

Comment: If I put it like that it gives me this error: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: And it have location like this: location = / { alias /var/www/html/pdf_carpet/file.pdf; default_type application/pdf; add_header Content-Disposition 'inline'; }

Comment: You are right, using an URI ended with slash will break given configuration (`ngx_http_index_module` will add an index file name to the URI, and in error log you'll see `/var/www/html/pdf_carpet/file.pdfindex.html" is not a directory` message). See an update to the answer for the solution.