# Serve PDF file by location & query parameter

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

How can I serve a PDF file at the below address:

`127.0.0.1/getMeThatFile/willYou?name=jane`

which is stored at a location:

`/usr/share/nginx/thatFile.pdf`

I tried to follow [Serve pdf file by location in nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42023339/serve-pdf-file-by-location-in-nginx), but couldn't get it to work:

```
server {
        location /getMeThatFile/willYou/ {
                alias /usr/share/nginx/;
                return 302 thatFile.pdf;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`/getMeThatFile/willYou` and `/getMeThatFile/willYou/` are different URIs. Your question suggests that the request will use the first, but your solution matches the second.

Use `location /getMeThatFile/willYou` to match both, or `location = /getMeThatFile/willYou` to match only the first. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

To return a single file, use `root` and `try_files`. For example:

```
location = /getMeThatFile/willYou {
    root /usr/share/nginx/;
    try_files /thatFile.pdf =404;
}
```

Assuming `thatFile.pdf` always exists, the `=404` is never reached, but is necessary as `try_files` requires at least two parameters. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.